# Populate word document with site columns from document library

Tags: 2013, workflow, rest, library, site-column

I got request to automate weekly reports based on daily reports.
Those reports are made in MS word. Now, I made up to almost half of job.
I created new document template for library, from which user will create daily reports. That template document has quick parts in itself. So I can populate site columns of the same name after he puts values in word document. I made it until this, so after user finishes word document report and saves it, site columns in library are populated with values.

Now comes part that I still didn't resolve.
I was thinking of creating word document that will take site columns from a library.

First what came on my mind was rest api workflow where I will take values from columns put it in dictionary and than post them in word document that would be created out of workflow.
I don't know how to put them in word document after I put them in dictionary.

*Word document would be created on user request, so I cannot have it already in library on my site.*

Any help would be appreciated. Also if you have any other idea how could I put values of site columns into word document I will consider them.

*Note:*
I must use word document as ingoing and outcome report.

Comment: you mean like quick parts? http://en.share-gate.com/blog/quick-tip-combining-word-and-metadata-through-quick-parts

Comment: no. I will edit my question to make more clarification.

Comment: Wild guess I cannot check right now. When you add a word document to the library, the associated list item metadata are populated from the document info. If the opposite is true, you could create an empty document in the library programmatically, and then update the list item with the required info. I don't know if this would work of if it is even applicable to your requisite but maybe it could be worth a try.

Comment: I am not sure if I understood you. If you could clarify it please. I already did a part when you add a document to library and than site columns in library are automatically populated based on quick parts from word document. Part where I have to paste values from site columns to new word document in different library is tricky for me.